# Insert a new record in access using oledb

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

Can I add a new record into access database which has 15 columns? It's very unconvinient for me to using this sql:

```
insert into Account(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15) Values(val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11,val12,val13,val14,val15)
```

There are 2 List consist columns name (name) and values (info). Example:

```
name[1]="col1";
info[1]="val1";
```

Is the ordinary of columns name important? Can I use this Sql:

```
insert into Account(col1) Values(val1)
```

After that I use an "update" sql and a "for-loop" to set values?
I also get an error:
The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.

Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do one insert before for loop and update in the for loop.

A sample code is given below.

```
string Query = "insert into Account(col1) Values(val1)";

// execute it
for(int i=1;i<name.count -1;i++)
{
  Query = "Update  Account set " + name[i] + " = " + info[i] + " where col1 = val1";
  // execute
}
```

Code not tested.

Comment: This will create multiple executes for single insert.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void insert(String[] name ,String[] info)
{
    String Names = "";
    String Cols = "";

    for(int i=0;i < name.Length;i++)
    {
        Names += (Names == "" ? "" :  ", ") + name[i];
        Cols += (Cols == "" ? "" : ", ") + "'" + info[i] + "'"; 
    }

    String Query = "insert into Account (" + Names + ") Values (" + Cols + ")";

    Console.WriteLine(Query);
}
```

Code not tested and note that I added single quotes for values assuming that all values are string type.

Comment: Made changes check now.